# Analyzing Java OO Code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, code-analysis

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730433/recommended-eclipse-plugins-for-java-source-code-analysis), but it's not what I'm looking for.

There used to be a plugin for JBuilder or Together that analyzed your code to find when one class depended too much on another class and things like that. **It suggested refactoring based on GoF design patterns.**

I have checked out PMD but it's not what I need, exactly. I'm looking for something more based on OO and less on Java syntax. **Is there anything for Eclipse that suggests OO refactorings of code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JDepend4Eclipse](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/jdepend4eclipse/index.html) is the eclipse plugin for [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) - a tool that analyzes package dependencies.

[Instantiations CodePro](http://www.instantiations.com/codepro/analytix/about.html) has dependecy analysis, but it's not a free plugin. It has a trial though.

Comment: Cool thanks Bozho, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should really have a look at [structure101](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/index.php). In my view the best dependency analyzing tool for Java on market. Maybe also have a look at IntelliJ, I think its analyze and refactoring features were always superiour to eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. That's not cheap, though

Answer (score 0):

We use this on projects sometimes

http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/33729